hdfs dfs -mkdir no such file or directory
I'm new to hadoop and I'm trying to create a directory in hdfs called input_dir. I have set up my vm, installed and started hadoop successfully.
This is the command that I run:
hdfs dfs -mkdir input_dir

And it keeps returning this error message:
mkdir: 'hdfs://hongdao-master:9000/user/hadoophongdao': No such file or directory 

Why is it giving this error?

The error is self descriptive. Did you try hdfs dfs -ls /user to see if that path exists?

I tried running the command `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hadoophongdao but got the error 'Namenode is in safe mode'. I tried disabling it, but it reactivates afterward.

I suggested running ls command, not mkdir

You need to first hadoop fs mkdir -p /user/hadoophongdao && hadoop fs -chmod -R 760 /user/hadoophongdao
Your user folder is used as the default parent folder without providing an absolute path, and it's not created by default for any user of HDFS.
Otherwise, you could use /tmp/input_dir

I tried running the command `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hadoophongdao but got the error 'Namenode is in safe mode'. I tried disabling it, but it reactivates afterward."

Sounds like a separate issue. I'd suggest looking at the namenode server process logs for any issues
